# Anyone know of a timecard app that uses GPS?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation

I'd like to log the hours I'm at work using the GPS on my iPhone. (It'd start logging when I get to work, then stop when I leave for lunch, etc)

If possible, I'd like to be able to log the time at multiple locations, so I could see for each day `time at home ~12h, work ~9h, commuting ~3h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/working-time-tracker/id426035526?mt=8) should do the trick.

- Has GPS functions
- Allows you to store and name multiple working locations
- Allows you to start, stop and set breaks on the timer.

How to use (from app description):

1. Download the app and wait till you arrive at your office.
2. Once there, activate the GPS tracking feature and go to the preferences page.
3. Register your current location as a working location (you can store more than one location for the same place, making the tracking more reliable).
4. Setup the amount of hours you plan to work (by default it is 8 hours).
5. If you leave the office before this amount of time expires, the timer will automatically enter in break mode (useful for lunch breaks)
6. When the timer reaches the planned working hours value, a ringtone will play and you will know that you can leave the office.
7. After the planned working time is passed, leaving the office will automatically stop the timer, and the working time info will be available in the history page.
8. After the initial setup you won't need to do anything else but
   keeping the app alive in background to keep track of your working
   time.

Comment: Neat, thanks - it looks exactly like what I'm after. I'll try it out today and tomorrow, and if it works I'll give you the bounty

Answer (score 4):

Another app that does this in a more generic, passive, long-term fashion is [Placeme](https://www.placemeapp.com/placeme/).

Answer (score 1):

[HoursTracker](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/hourstracker-free-time-tracking/id336456412?mt=8) for iOS. Perfect. Excellent.

Location Awareness* clocks in for you when you arrive. *Optional in-app purchase $0.99.

I set my work location using 3G or Wi Fi. Then, every time I arrive near my work location the app clocks in. And every time I leave it clocks out.

Comment: Can you please explain how this app will fulfill the requirements mentioned in the question?

Comment: Location Awareness* clocks in for you when you arrive. *Optional in-app purchase $0.99.

Comment: You track hours spent in many job locations and then summarize hours by day, week, month, job, and pay period.

Answer (score 0):

I think [TSheets Time Tracker with GPS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tsheets-time-tracker-with-gps/id381821749?mt=8) will suit your needs.

According to [their website](http://blog.tsheets.com/iphone-time-tracker), they support logging events based on the GPS location:

> Some of the time tracking features already available:
>
> - In/out punch clock time tracking with GPS

An other solution would be [GPS Timesheets](http://www.gpstimesheets.com/) where you'll have to connect your GPS to this software and it will generate a Timesheet for you.

Comment: I've installed the TSheets app, and there doesn't appear to be any way to start/stop the clock via GPS - it simply logs GPS location periodically and when clocking in/out.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? Logging where, how long and when you are in a place?

Comment: gpstimesheets.com doesn't appear to do anything - there's no register link. From what it describes, you upload your GPS logged data and it formats it as timesheets - not what I require.

Comment: I want the app to run in the background and log how long I am at work from my GPS coordinates, without me having to click Start/Stop. Think GeoFencing

Answer (score 0):

IFTTT
IF This Then That

The app will let you use your built in GPS and it will automatically trigger you have entered your defined work area. Same for if you leave. When it triggers it makes a quick event on a calender of choice. Really handy.

Answer (score -1):

[busybusy](https://www.busybusy.com/) is a great app if you need a GPS time clock. It has great features and for one user it's free.